# NHibernate retrieve data from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, criteria

I have 3 tables in mysql

```
User
---------------------
`id` (auto increment)(PK)
`user_name`
`password`
`first_name`
`last_name`
`created_at`
`modified_at`
`email`
```

```
User_Role 
-----------------------
`user_id` (PK)
`role_id` (PK)
```

```
Role
----------------------
`id`(PK)
`name`
```

I want to execute the query

```
SELECT u.*,r.name
FROM user u
JOIN user_role ur ON UR.user_id=u.id
JOIN role r on UR.role_id=r.id
```

Can anyone help me with the criteria in NHibernate?

I tried with this code

```
ICriteria Criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User));
Criteria.CreateAlias("User_Role", "User_Role");
Criteria.CreateAlias("User_Role.Role", "UsrRole");
Criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("id", Uid));
```

but it's showing an error.

---

I want to fetch the information from these tables with the query

`SELECT u.*,r.name`
`FROM user u`
`JOIN user_role ur ON UR.user_id=u.id`
`JOIN role r on UR.role_id=r.id`

I tried with this code

`ICriteria Criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User));`
`Criteria.CreateAlias("User_Role", "User_Role");`
`Criteria.CreateAlias("User_Role.Role", "UsrRole");`
`Criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("id", Uid));`

but its showing error

Comment: what criteria do you mean. next would be something like : where r.name='something'

Comment: [How Do I format my code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate will generate the necessary queries automatically. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations . Then think about your classes and mappings.

Might look like

```
namespace FirstSolution.Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                   assembly="FirstSolution" 
                   namespace="FirstSolution.Domain">

  <class name="User">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="user_name" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```